# Python network programming project sources

Tags: python, networking

I am currently a student and next semester I am taking a network programming course in python. I need to propose a network project on which I'll work during the semester before it starts. I wanted to ask if anybody knows any good sources of the project for my topic. I can include anything related to networking and security.

Comment: "Network" is very broad, more specifically what will the course teach?

Comment: UDP, TCP, Sockets, TSL and SSL, web applications and screen craping, server architecture anp proxies, packets inspetctions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might be off-topic for StackOverflow; however, you can consider implementing a simple online chat room.

The main advantage of this topic is that it's as probably as simple as you can get to demonstrate application of core concepts in networking and security.

You'll be able to do a bit of architecture as well:

- Server Backend: Django, or another framework for Python? Is event-driven architecture appropriate here? Publish-subscribe?
- Client UI/Model: You should technically still use the Model-View-Controller pattern, even though the model here would just be a "proxy" for the model on the server.
- Serialized Mediums: JSON, YAML, YAML?
- ORM for user accounts / history

It's also a safe project because, while it's not overly ambitious, you can keep adding features to it **as long as you have more time left**; I'm sure you can think of many possible features for a chatroom =)

Comment: Thank you. Sounds intresting.